# What is correct sentence for not to or to not

Tags: phrase-usage, spoken-english

Which one is correct sentence?

1. The most dangerous thing in the world is: Not To Try
2. The most dangerous thing in the world is: To Not Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The most dangerous thing in the world is to not try" is correct, although it seems incomplete.

A better alternative would be: "The most dangerous thing in the world is not trying"

Comment: 'Not to try' is more emphatic, if a bit 'wordy' or intentionally slightly archaic.